# Automatically set SSH user

Tags: ssh

I have one ssh server that I seldom connect to and which requires to use a different user than the one I use to log in to my system. When I just execute `ssh example.com` then ssh will automatically use my default user foo@example.com to connect. This will not work, because the server expects me to connect with a special user `xyz12345@example.com`. Additionally, the server has a strong blocking and banning policy. So when I use the wrong password a few times, then I am automatically blocked for half an hour or even banned. Because I connect so seldom, I tend to forget that I need to use a special user to connect, and it can be very annoying if I am blocked for half an hour or even banned.

What I am looking for is a way configure my local ssh client and tell it: **"When ever I am connecting to example.com, I want you to automatically connect with user xyz12345 and not with my current user."**

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can set it up in your ssh client config.

Add to your `.ssh/config`

```
Host example.com
     User xyz12345
```

From [man ssh_config](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh_config%205):

```
User     Specifies the user to log in as. This can be useful when a dif-
         ferent user name is used on different machines.  This saves the
         trouble of having to remember to give the user name on the com-
         mand line.
```

Comment: This is also useful for those times when they are virtual hosting, you connect as user@example.com@example.com so your username would then be user@example.com

Answer (score 1):

I would use an alias in your `~/.<shell>rc` script:

```
alias mycmd='ssh xyz12345@example.com'
```

then type:

```
source ~/.<shell>rc
```

But you can also do this: [A way better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197559/ssh-configuration-override-the-default-username)

Comment: I was rather looking for something that directly affects ssh. As I said, I will not connect to this server so often and I tend to forget that I need to use a special user, so I will likely also forget that I have setup an alias and just try to connect with `ssh example.com`. I want a way such  that ssh actively prevents me from doing this. Either by warning me or by automatically using the correct user for this particular server.

Comment: I understand, I added a link in my answer, the solution is a way better.

Comment: Perfect, thats exactly what I was looking for.